# Yii, CGridView not showing records of a certain attribute

Tags: yii, null, records, cgridview

So I have created records and each has their own particular `Service` field. They are all filled up (not null).

In the MySQL database, there are also records of that field `Service`

But in my CGridView, my `Service` field is all blank. All the `Service` fields are blank for all the records. When I click on the button `View` - The one with the magnifying glass, it says `Service - Not Set`

Can I know what may cause the problem? Please help me Thanks!

**UPDATED WITH CGRIDVIEW CODE**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'booking-grid',
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-view grid-size'),
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name'=>'date',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center', 'height'=>'50px', 'width'=>'80px'),
        'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('height'=>'30px'),
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'timeStart',
        'header'=>"Time",
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center', 'width'=>'80px'),
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'client_id',
        'value'=>'GxHtml::valueEx($data->client)',
        'filter'=>GxHtml::listDataEx(Client::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'200px'),
    ),
    array(
            'name'=>'service_id',
            'value'=>'GxHtml::valueEx($data->service)',
            'filter'=>GxHtml::listDataEx(Service::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)),
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'complete',
        'header'=>'Status',
        'value' => '($data->complete == 0) ? Yii::t(\'app\', \'Open\') : Yii::t(\'app\', \'Close\')',                   
        'filter' => array('0' => Yii::t('app', 'Open'), '1' => Yii::t('app', 'Close')),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'60px', 'style'=>'text-align:center'),
    ),
    'remarks',
    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'visible'=>true,
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'70px'),
        'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}{changeComplete}',
        'buttons'=>array(               
            'view' => array(
                'visible'=>"true",
            ),
            'update' => array(
                'visible'=>"true",
            ),
            'delete' => array(
                'visible'=>"UserIdentity::isRoleMember('Admin')",
            ),
            'changeComplete' => array(
                'visible' => '$data->complete=="0"',
                'imageUrl' => 'images/complete.png',
                'options' => array(
                    'title' => 'Complete',
                ),
                'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("booking/changeComplete", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                'click' => "function(){
                    $.fn.yiiGridView.update(\"booking-grid\", {
                        type:'POST',
                        url:$(this).attr('href'),
                        success:function(data) {
                            $.fn.yiiGridView.update(\"booking-grid\");
                        }
                    })
                    return false;
                }",
            ),
        ),
    ),
))); ?>
```

I have tried looking at other CGridViews with the same field, they look the same and they're working perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you post your cgridview?

Comment: Already added it in. Please have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `$data->service`. Probably your data has a relation with the `Service` entity. So for accessing attributes of `Service` you should use `$data->service->attributeName`.

Comment: There's still an error. It says, "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: $data->service is null. This means there isn't any service for your data.

Comment: But there is inside my database. It's just that whenever I click on the admin.php OR the view.php, there's nothing in the Service. It says 'Not Set'